My State Flow wont update the values in the viewmodel
I have this code for image analysis, and I'm trying to pass the processed text data list to the ViewModel. The text is recognized, but it doesn't get properly sent to the ViewModel. I logged the data, and the image analysis recognizes the text, processes it, maps it to a list, and successfully updates _detectedText.value. However, when I log the ViewModel, it initially receives the data but then stops. I don’t know what to do—I’ve already been working on this for about two weeks.
Image analisys code:

class TextRecognitionAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    //Throttling time for the text recognition 1000L - 1 second
    companion object {
        const val THROTTLE_TIMEOUT_MS = 1_000L
    }

    //defining the coroutine scope and the text recognizer
    private val scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())
    private val textRecognizer: TextRecognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS)

    // StateFlow to hold the detected text
    private val _detectedText = MutableStateFlow<List<DetectedTextData>>(emptyList())
    val detectedText: StateFlow<List<DetectedTextData>> get() = _detectedText


    @androidx.annotation.OptIn(ExperimentalGetImage::class)
    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {

        scope.launch {
            val mediaImage: Image = imageProxy.image ?: run { imageProxy.close(); return@launch }
            val inputImage: InputImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

            suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
                textRecognizer.process(inputImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { visionText: Text ->
                        // Process and update detected text
                        Log.d("TextRecognitionAnalyzer", "Detected Text: ${visionText.text}")
                        _detectedText.value = ProcessDetectedText(visionText).processText().toList()
                        Log.d("TextRecognitionAnalyzer state flow", "Detected Text in State: ${_detectedText.value}")
                    }
                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                        continuation.resume(Unit)
                    }
            }

            delay(THROTTLE_TIMEOUT_MS)
        }.invokeOnCompletion { exception ->
            exception?.printStackTrace()
            imageProxy.close()
        }
    }
}

Viewmodel code:

@HiltViewModel
class ClassRoomAddViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val textRecognitionAnalyzer: TextRecognitionAnalyzer 
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _addClassRoomState = MutableStateFlow(AddClassRoomState())
    val addClassRoomState: StateFlow<AddClassRoomState> = _addClassRoomState

    init {
        Log.d("ViewModel", "Analyzer injected: $textRecognitionAnalyzer")
        collectDetectedText()
        Log.d("ViewModel", "Initialized ViewModel")
    }

    private fun collectDetectedText() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            textRecognitionAnalyzer.detectedText.collect { updatedText ->
                Log.d("ViewModel", "Collected Detected Text: $updatedText")
                _addClassRoomState.value = _addClassRoomState.value.copy(
                    detectedText = updatedText
                )
                Log.d("ViewModel", "State Updated: ${_addClassRoomState.value}")
            }
        }
    }
}


You only need this in your view model:
val addClassRoomState: StateFlow<AddClassRoomState> = textRecognitionAnalyzer.detectedText
    .mapLatest { AddClassRoomState(it) }
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = AddClassRoomState(),
    )

You shouldn't collect flows in the view model, flows should just be transformed.
